# Grafana graph hover list shows data point from previous date

Tags: graph, grafana

When you create a line chart in grafana you can hover the line to see the data points exact values. However if a metric for a specific time is `null` it gets the first metric from a previous date.

[image: the problem]

I'm asking myself: Am I doing something wrong, or is this just how grafana works.

How can I change this behaviour so I only show the data in the hover tooltip from the date that is actually hovered.

Answer (score 0):

well, i think this is how it works. why do you want that? maybe you can use alternative ways

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your using the connected option to handle your null values which enables the toot tip to snap to the closest previous value (or only value in time range).

Click edit on your panel and go to visualization settings. Under `Stacking & Null value` options change `Null value` from `connected` to `null`.

The go down to the legend options and under `Hide series` enable the option to hide null values in series (`With only nulls`).

The tool tip will now show no data values for series that don't have data at a time. The tradeoff is now your series won't be connected and the will be gaps in the visualization.